# Sitecore Experience Analytics error : Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: partialViewName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.2

After upgrading sitecore to 8.2 from 8.1 im facing some issues with accessing sitecore/shell dashboard it starts throwing error after enabling xDb on CMS. I've gone through their standard configs but cannot figure out the reason for this.

Below are the exception i see when accessing /sitecore

```
    [ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: partialViewName]
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +474
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.Renderings.Rendering.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +773
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +128
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.Renderings.ControlsExtension.Rendering(Controls controls, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, String renderingItemId, String controlId, String dataSource, Object parameters) +648
   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.RenderingHelper.CreateRenderingAt(String renderindItemId, String controlId, String parent, Object parameters, String datasource, String contentPlaceholder) +97
   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.RenderingHelper.MakeLineChart(String controlId, String parent, String data, String placeholderProperty, String strMetrics) +808
   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass4.<EmbedChart>b__1(String entry) in d:\Sitecore82\SitecoreCMS8.2_V0.4\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ExperienceAnalytics\Common\Layouts\Renderings\ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart.cshtml:35
   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.RenderingHelper.MakeAdvancedExpander(String controlId, String parent, String title, Boolean isCollapsible, Action`1 nextControl) +214
   ASP.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EmbedChart>b__0(TextWriter __razor_helper_writer) in d:\Sitecore82\SitecoreCMS8.2_V0.4\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ExperienceAnalytics\Common\Layouts\Renderings\ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart.cshtml:24
   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Applications_ExperienceAnalytics_Common_Layouts_Renderings_ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Sitecore82\SitecoreCMS8.2_V0.4\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ExperienceAnalytics\Common\Layouts\Renderings\ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart.cshtml:13
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +353

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Common/Layouts/Renderings/ExperienceAnalyticsLineChart.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Mvc.Presentation.ExperienceAnalyticsLineChartViewModel, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +906
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +27
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +62
   (Object , Object[] ) +83
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +445
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +20
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +219
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ItemRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +307
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter output, Item item) +355
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +201
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +128
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ControlsExtension.ItemRenderer(Controls controls, Rendering rendering) +225
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Common_SubAppRenderes_SubAppRenderer_cshtml.Execute() +383
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +353
```

Not able to figure where the issue is caused due to mismatch configs or sitecore bug ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issues.

- Check if you have all the files in Sitecore folder. Looks like you are missing something (Install Sitecore 8.2. compare the Sitecore folder for it and your application. You can use the Winmerge or KDiffTool)
- Try Opening /Sitecore/login or /sitecore/shell can you open it?
- Does your website works?
- Verify/Compare the DLLs from Bin folder from your application and Sitecore 8.2.
- Verify/Compare the Config files from App_Config folder from your application and Sitecore 8.2.

Comment: I can login into sitecore fine also site works without any exception. I've cross checked those config seems to be ok.
But i cannot access /shell i.e the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve issue as it was happening due certain items where skip duration the installation. So tried re-installing in fresh database and errors gone.